# D3.js radar chart label

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, radar-chart

I'm new to D3.js. Following a example I managed to plot radar chart from some data. However now I want to know the label of the corresponding line on clicking a line. I know there is a 'on click' event that can be attached and I get a list of attributes like pageX and pageY, but however how do i find the label. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you add an example of running code, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I was able to get the label using the following : event.srcElement.__data__.area

Comment: glade its working for you, but you should have added your code snippet in the question.